# How to check if currently running in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I've been struggling to find a good way to distinguish between running in Google Cloud Build or in a different environment. Google Cloud Build has default substitutions like `PROJECT_ID` but those don't actually show up in the environment unless you explicitly put them in under `env`. This has already bitten me once because I removed "unused environment mappings" and broke the detection I'd written.

Is there something more foolproof I can run like an API call to get information about the current service account or the current build?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65821436/18265702). Also can you explain clearly what you are looking for? Also have a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52840187/18265702).

Comment: "but those don't actually show up in the environment unless you explicitly put them in under env." What do mean here? 
Google Cloud build with the new releases started to ask the user for a special service account having the required permission. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni that's close but manually including all the environment variables every time isn't ideal. I'll use the check for the service account if there's not better solution but I don't want something an irregular service account to trip up the platform detection.

Comment: Can you check about using `Substitutions` by referring to this [Blog](https://timothyreynolds.co.uk/words/2019/securing-environment-variables-in-google-cloud-build) and [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I mention substitutions in my question, I found them too finicky because most of the scripts are complex enough to be refactored out into a shell script. I found requiring some substitution like `PROJECT_ENV` to always be mapped into the environment to just lead other developers to ask why it wasn't being detected as running in Google Cloud Build.

Comment: `an API call to get information about the current service account or the current build?` looking for something similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338863/cloud-build-api-call-to-check-information-regarding-the-latest-build) and [doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds)?